# Issues while installing igraph on Mac (with python 2.7)

Tags: macos, python-2.7, igraph

I have read some questions and followed guidelines about this topic but didn't find any solution.
I am trying to install **igraph** for Python 2.7 in a virtual environment on Mac. I am not using Anaconda (I used to have conflicts with other packages)
I followed the guidelines from the igraph website, using Homebrew and from [this](https://gist.github.com/Niknafs/6b50d9df9d5396a2e92e) source code  but I still have the same issue :

`ImportError: dlopen(/Users/alexandreattia/Desktop/Work/py27_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so, 2): Symbol not found: _iconv
  Referenced from: /Users/alexandreattia/Desktop/Work/py27_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/alexandreattia/Desktop/Work/py27_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so`

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found that my issues were caused by my python binary path in my virtual env. I had to change the python binary path when I created my virtualenv (`virtualenv -p /python/path/`) with the same that the one I used with homebrew (it can be found in `brew config`).